# GIT: Any way to commit on multiple repos?

Tags: git

I know this isn't recommended, but I do have folders with multiple projects that I like to keep up to date.

Is there a command that will look for each git repository in a folder and send the following commands..

```
git add -u 
git add .
git commit -m 'Latest'
```

So I could just cd into some folder, then run a command that gets them all updated?

**This is not a submodules question**

Comment: It may be that the answer is a .sh

Comment: Although there are ways to do this, I don't even recommend doing the above for a single repository, let alone a bunch of them. I think treating your commits as "mini code reviews" helps a lot in keeping a clean history - which helps a lot in the long term in code maintenance: cross revision bugfixes, removing unwanted patches, etc.

Comment: Did you really not see the first thing I wrote?!

Comment: I did. But I hate working on repositories with random commits, so I can't stop myself from putting the above comment everywhere. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

why don't you use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for DIR in `ls`;
do
    if [ -d $DIR/.git ];
    then
            echo "updating location: " $DIR;
            cd $DIR
            # your commands here...
            git add -u 
            git add .
            git commit -m 'Latest'

            cd ..
    fi
done
```

Comment: can you make it so it's copy and paste? I'm not sure how to add my commands :\

Comment: @Kirk: I hope you're using a *nix system, so you really just have to literally place the commands from your grey box between `# your commands here...` and `cd ..`

Comment: @Scolytus it should work also in mingw (tested),  msysgit (not tested) on windows.

Comment: Oh, does it always come with `/bin/bash`? Good to know... I guess you will also have to tell windows how to execute the script or execute it from within a mingw shell, right?

Comment: the first line is for the shell to know which interpreter to use. You can use any shell you like if the code is compatible with it. If you run in from within mingw it will work because mingw has /bin/bash.

Comment: The `-u` adds the deletes for commiting. One could add git push, but I can imagine that it will fail due to timing when connecting to a server. A workaround could be sleep().

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you are looking for something like `mr` ([homepage](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/mr/)). I use it to update a bunch of repos all at once, but it can be configured to do any stuff you want. It's also available as Ubuntu and Debian package in official repos. Otherwise you can just write a script that does the stuff for you.

Comment: Sounds promising, can I install the source code and let's say leave subversion (iihh) away? On your site you offer git clone, what is it for?

Answer (score 2):

Disclamer: This is own code. I have no financial benefit if you use or fork it, but it was written for exactly this kind of scenario and maybe it helps. ;)

I wrote gitglue. You can tag repositories and execute arbitrary commands tag-based. Check [this tutorial about gitglue](https://inktrap.org/code/gitglue-your-repos-together.html) or fork [gitglue on Github.](https://github.com/inktrap/gitglue)

Answer (score 1):

I use a bash script (in my `.bashrc`) to run multiple time the same git command on several repos.
The bash hardcodes the repo location but it could easily be changed. One of the issues with running multiple times the same command is correctly passing the quoted `"` arguments, typically `-m " commit message"`

I run those command like this:

`mgit commit -a -m "my commit message"` where mgit is a alias in my .bashrc.

This works for any git commant (I least the one I tested and used on a daily basis), eg:

`mgit status -uno`, `mgit pull`

## function parsing the git arguments

This function ensure any quoted argument (after the `-m` are correctly handled)

```
parse_git_args()
{
    git_args=""
    end_comment=""
    for var in "$@"
    do
        if [[ $var == '-m' ]];
        then
            git_args+=" -m \""
            end_comment="\"" 
        else
            git_args+=" $var"
        fi
    done
    git_args+=$end_comment

    echo $git_args
}
```

## function running the same command on several repos

```
multiple_git_func()
{
    start=$(pwd)
    git_args=$(parse_git_args $@)
    root=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel` #find the repo from which the command was run

    # go to root apply command and then go to sub repos (hardcoded location wrt root)
    cd $root
    echo "=============================="
    echo "issuing git $git_args on $root"
    eval "git $git_args"


    cd repo2 # repo2 is installed in root, could be anywhere else relative to root
    echo "=============================="
    echo "issuing git $git_args on repo2"
    eval "git $git_args"
   
    #go back to initial folder
    cd $start
}
```

## alias in .bashrc

`alias mgit=multiple_git_func`